# Determining the output of the following assembly codes

Tags: assembly

Dump of assembler code for function phase_1:

```
0x08048bcc <phase_1+0>: push   %ebp
0x08048bcd <phase_1+1>: mov    %esp,%ebp
0x08048bcf <phase_1+3>: sub    $0x10,%esp
0x08048bd2 <phase_1+6>: push   $0x8049808
0x08048bd7 <phase_1+11>:        pushl  0x8(%ebp)
0x08048bda <phase_1+14>:        call   0x8048f9c(strings_not_equal)
0x08048bdf <phase_1+19>:        add    $0x10,%esp
0x08048be2 <phase_1+22>:        test   %eax,%eax
0x08048be4 <phase_1+24>:        je     0x8048beb(phase_1+31)
0x08048be6 <phase_1+26>:        call   0x804951c(explode_bomb)
0x08048beb <phase_1+31>:        leave
0x08048bec <phase_1+32>:        ret
```

Dump of assembler code for function strings_not_equal:

```
0x08048f9c <strings_not_equal+0>:       push   %ebp
0x08048f9d <strings_not_equal+1>:       mov    %esp,%ebp
0x08048f9f <strings_not_equal+3>:       push   %edi
0x08048fa0 <strings_not_equal+4>:       push   %esi
0x08048fa1 <strings_not_equal+5>:       push   %ebx
0x08048fa2 <strings_not_equal+6>:       mov    0x8(%ebp),%esi
0x08048fa5 <strings_not_equal+9>:       mov    0xc(%ebp),%edi
0x08048fa8 <strings_not_equal+12>:      push   %esi
0x08048fa9 <strings_not_equal+13>:      call   0x8048f83(string_length)
0x08048fae <strings_not_equal+18>:      mov    %eax,%ebx
0x08048fb0 <strings_not_equal+20>:      push   %edi
0x08048fb1 <strings_not_equal+21>:      call   0x8048f83 (string_length)
0x08048fb6 <strings_not_equal+26>:      add    $0x8,%esp
0x08048fb9 <strings_not_equal+29>:      mov    $0x1,%edx
0x08048fbe <strings_not_equal+34>:      cmp    %eax,%ebx
0x08048fc0 <strings_not_equal+36>:      jne    0x8048fe6 (strings_not_equal+74)
0x08048fc2 <strings_not_equal+38>:      jmp    0x8048fcb (strings_not_equal+47)
0x08048fc4 <strings_not_equal+40>:      mov    $0x1,%edx
0x08048fc9 <strings_not_equal+45>:      jmp    0x8048fe6 (strings_not_equal+74)
0x08048fcb <strings_not_equal+47>:      mov    %esi,%edx
0x08048fcd <strings_not_equal+49>:      mov    %edi,%ecx
0x08048fcf <strings_not_equal+51>:      cmpb   $0x0,(%esi)
0x08048fd2 <strings_not_equal+54>:      je     0x8048fe1 (strings_not_equal+69)
0x08048fd4 <strings_not_equal+56>:      mov    (%edx),%al
0x08048fd6 <strings_not_equal+58>:      cmp    (%ecx),%al
0x08048fd8 <strings_not_equal+60>:      jne    0x8048fc4 (strings_not_equal+40)
0x08048fda <strings_not_equal+62>:      inc    %edx
0x08048fdb <strings_not_equal+63>:      inc    %ecx
0x08048fdc <strings_not_equal+64>:      cmpb   $0x0,(%edx)
0x08048fdf <strings_not_equal+67>:      jne    0x8048fd4 (strings_not_equal+56)
0x08048fe1 <strings_not_equal+69>:      mov    $0x0,%edx
0x08048fe6 <strings_not_equal+74>:      mov    %edx,%eax
0x08048fe8 <strings_not_equal+76>:      lea    0xfffffff4(%ebp),%esp
0x08048feb <strings_not_equal+79>:      pop    %ebx
0x08048fec <strings_not_equal+80>:      pop    %esi
0x08048fed <strings_not_equal+81>:      pop    %edi
0x08048fee <strings_not_equal+82>:      leave
0x08048fef <strings_not_equal+83>:      ret
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What specific problem has you confused? http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 4):

For one, you should probably tag this as homework or at least mention it in the question (I think "homework" might be considered an undesired meta-tag now - I'm not sure). I did this assignment when I was in college, and in fact I think I still have it on my laptop. You should really be up-front about this because SO will generally frown upon providing direct and exact answers to homework questions. People are very willing to help, but transparency is nice.

In answer to your actual question: the code you posted has no output. It doesn't print anything. All that `phase_1` does is call a string compare function and then "explode" if you didn't enter the proper password.

What I'm guessing you meant by this question was "What string does the `strings_not_equal` function use in its comparison?" Since the whole point of the assignment is to use the debugger and reverse-engineering techniques to figure out the passwords to each phase, I will leave that as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: I almost spoiled his homework, thanks for pointing that out ;).

Comment: @Jens Mühlenhof: Ha, sure. For the curious [here's a copy](http://robert.narnia.homeunix.com/Fall2009/301/bomblab.pdf) of the handout I was given for this assignment (from my professor's server). It was one of my favorites!

Comment: I don't know how to use the debugger to figure out the answers...

Comment: @Brian: Well, there's a pretty good GDB tutorial [here](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~gilpin/tutorial/) that you can start with. You may also want to look into the Unix `strings` command/program. It can also provide some very useful information. If you still need some help after that, then I'd recommend either asking your professor directly or possibly posting a new SO question specific to any debugging problems you have.

Comment: Indeed, you should mention if it's homework in the question, if it matters; but ["the homework tag, like other so-called 'meta' tags, is now discouraged."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10812)